# Is there a way to set the tab length in any other unit than pixels in TeXworks?

Tags: indentation, editors, texworks

OK, this might be more for http://superuser.com, but I guess I should give it a try here:

So, I use [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) from the [TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) repo. Or at least, I started to, since I need to have a LaTeX suite installed on Windows. I used TeXLive for Windows, it comes with TeXworks. The only editor I'm used to, is Vim. TeXworks seems to be a good editor, though.

Now, the way it treats indentation, is really *weird*. I can set the <kbd>Tab</kbd> length in pixel. In other words, I can assign a width in pixel for every tab character:
[image]

What I would like, though, is a tab size in characters. And most importantly: I need the tab key to produce spaces. I am one of those people, that use two or four (depending on the language) spaces, instead of tabs. Is that possible with TeXworks?

In case it's not possible, I'm going to have to ditch TeXworks for [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [currently open feature request](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=400&q=tab%20width) for TeXworks, so as of this time, there is no way to change the tabs to spaces.

There are other editors for Windows that have good LaTeX support.  See:

[LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/2693)

In that list, Vim is included, as it has very good LaTeX support. There's a version for Windows, I believe.

Comment: Yeah, I used Vim on Windows, but I'm in a scenario, where I have several users needing to use LaTeX on Windows. My users have been using MikTeX up until now, but I want them to move on to TeXLive and since TeXworks is in there, why not use it. Now, my Users aren't too techie, so Vim is a bit... much, for them...

Comment: But then moving to Notepad++ doesn't seem like a good choice. There are other cross-platform editors with better support for LaTeX.

Comment: well, it doesn't have to bee exactly cross platform, I had my users using TeXnicCenter. I liked TeXworks almost better, though. I'm used to Notepad++, so I guess it is alright. I can't push my users to Vim, though, the learning curve would be too steep.

Comment: Also, the feature request is two years old, and I didn't see much change in the program. But what I really don't understand, is why they did that kind of weird tab display in the first place.